# Submit and re-submit abstract id number

Tags: php

I have an abstract submission form. Clients submits abstracts and i collect them in my database. The form has an option that clients can make changes to the submitted abstract through a link that is generated in the confirmation mail. I need when they resubmit their abstract, the submission id that i receive in my database to be like: '' submission id = 1a, or submission id=1b if they resubmit for second time etc.'' . So i need the number to be the same but with a letter next to it every time that they resubmit.

Now, regardless how many changes they make in their abstract the submission id number remains the same. ( only number )

**Here is the php code for the resubmit form :**

```
<?php

require_once './lib.php';
include_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

function reSendSubmissions() {
    $ids = array(108, 117, 142, 170, 171, 154, 153, 146, 159, 255, 109, 185, 250, 257, 151, 235, 234, 233, 273, 275, 281, 355, 366, 373, 231, 365, 384, 425, 234, 290, 303, 153, 154, 391, 388);
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $sql = 'SELECT a.`title`, a.`speaker`, a.`submisssion_timestampt`, a.`submissionid`, a.`pincode`, b.`email` '
                . 'FROM `submissions` a INNER JOIN `personaldata` b ON(b.`pdataid`=a.`pdata_id`) '
                . 'WHERE a.`submissionid`="' . (int) $id . '" '
                . 'LIMIT 1';
        $db = new dbrequest();
        $data = array();
        if ($submission = $db->generalSelect($sql)) {
            if (!$submission[0])
                continue;
            $submission = $submission[0];
            $data['title'] = $submission['title'];
            $data['speaker'] = $submission['speaker'];
            $data['date'] = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($submission['submisssion_timestampt']));
            $data['time'] = date('H:i', strtotime($submission['submisssion_timestampt']));
            $data['no'] = $submission['submissionid'];
            $data['link'] = 'http://www.e-bass.org/22ndcongress/form/edit.php?pcode=' . $submission['pincode'];
//            maildata::mailSenderTest($submission['email'], $data);
            echo $id.'-'.$submission['email'].'<br/>';
        }
    }
}

reSendSubmissions();
```

**end the php code for the submit form :**

```
<?php

if ((isset($_POST['firstname'])) && (isset($_POST['email']))) {
    require_once 'lib.php';
    (isset($_POST['poster'])) ? $poster = $_POST['poster'] : $poster = null;
    (isset($_POST['contestant'])) ? $contestant = $_POST['contestant'] : $contestant = null;
    $newdata = new dbrequest();
    $pdata = array(
        'firstname' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'firstname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
        'lastname' => filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lastname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
        'address' => $_POST['address'],
        'city' => $_POST['city'],
        'poc' => $_POST['poc'],
        'country' => $_POST['country'],
        'workingplace' => $_POST['workingplace'],
        'specialization' => $_POST['specialization'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'cellphone' => $_POST['cellphone'],
        'phone' => $_POST['phone'],
        'fax' => $_POST['fax']);
    $authors = $_POST['authors1'] . '-' . $_POST['title1'] . '-' . $_POST['university1'] . ';' . $_POST['authors2'] . '-' . $_POST['title2'] . '-' . $_POST['university2'] . ';' . $_POST['authors3'] . '-' . $_POST['title3'] . '-' . $_POST['university3'] . ';' . $_POST['authors4'] . '-' . $_POST['title4'] . '-' . $_POST['university4'] . ';' . $_POST['authors5'] . '-' . $_POST['title5'] . '-' . $_POST['university5'];
    if ((isset($_POST['update'])) && ($_POST['update'] == 'true')) {
        $updateSubData = array(
            'authors' => $authors,
            'speaker' => trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'speaker_firstname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) . ' ' . trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'speaker_lastname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)),
            'title' => $_POST['title'],
            'presentation_id' => $_POST['presentation'],
            'topic_id' => $_POST['topic'],
            'poster' => $poster,
            'contestant' => $contestant,
            'summary' => $_POST['summary']);
        $newdata->updatePersonalData($pdata, $_POST['pdata_id']);
        $newdata->updateSumission($updateSubData, $_POST['submissionid']);
        $html = <<<EOD
                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <title>Paper Submited</title>
                                </head>
                <body style="margin:0; padding:0">
                <div style="width:600px;height:auto; margin:0 auto;">
                <div id="header"></div>
                <div id="content">
                <h3>The processing of your paper is done successfully.</h3>
                <p style="text-align:center">Thank you for your participation.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </body>
                </html>
EOD;
        print $html;
    } else {
        $speakerPost = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'speaker_firstname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) . ' ' . trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'speaker_lastname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
        $speakerDB = $newdata->metriseOmilites($speakerPost);
        $speakerDB = $speakerDB[0]['single_speaker'];
        if ($speakerDB >= 1) {
            $html = <<<EOD
                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <title>SUBMISSION FORM</title>
                                </head>
                <body style="margin:0; padding:0">
                <div style="width:600px;height:auto; margin:0 auto;">
                <               <div style="width:600px;height:auto; margin:0 auto;background-color:#4F6B92">
                <h3>There was an error in your application.</h3>
                <p style="text-align:center">The presenter chosen is already registered in 1 paper.</p>
                <p style="text-align:center"><a href="javascript:history.back(1)">Click here to return to the Submission Form.</a></p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </body>
                </html>
EOD;
            print $html;
            exit();
        }
        $newdata->insertPersonalData($pdata);
        $pdata_id = $newdata->selectLastInsert('personaldata', 'pdataid');
        $pdata_id = $pdata_id[0]['pdataid'];
        $pcode = mt_rand(1, 99999);
        $pcode = md5(time() . $pcode);
        $pcode = substr($pcode, 0, 22);
        $submission = array(
            'pincode' => $pcode,
            'pdata_id' => $pdata_id,
            'authors' => $authors,
            'speaker' => trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'speaker_firstname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) . ' ' . trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'speaker_lastname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)),
            'title' => $_POST['title'],
            'presentation_id' => $_POST['presentation'],
            'topic_id' => $_POST['topic'],
            'poster' => $poster,
            'contestant' => $contestant,
            'summary' => $_POST['summary']);
        $newdata->insertSubmission($submission);
        $submissionNo = $newdata->selectLastInsert('submissions', 'submissionid');
        $submissionNo = $submissionNo[0]['submissionid'];
        $neoMail = new maildata();
        $datamail = array(
            'title' => $_POST['title'],
            'speaker' => $_POST['speaker_firstname'] . ' ' . $_POST['speaker_lastname'],
            'date' => date('d-m-Y'),
            'time' => date('H:i'),
            'no' => $submissionNo,
            'link' => 'http://' . $newdata->domainURL . '/edit.php?pcode=' . $pcode);
        $neoMail->mailSender($_POST['email'], $datamail);
        $html = <<<EOD
                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <title>SUBMISSION OF PAPER</title>
                                </head>
                <body style="margin:0; padding:0">
                <div style="width:600px;height:auto; margin:0 auto;">
                <div id="header"></div>
                <div id="content">
                <h3>Submitting your work done successfully.</h3>
                <p>You receive the relevant proof of submission to the email address you provided in the application form.</p>
                <p style="text-align:center">Thank you for your participation.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </body>
                </html>
EOD;
        print $html;
    }
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Have separate columns in your database for `id` and `version`. Change only version when submission is updated. As simple as that. Too simple to post this as an answer huh.

Comment: unfortunately is not so simple for me, as i just started to learn. Is it possible for you to be more specific? What exactly should i add to the code and where?

Comment: Okay, so here we go, see the answer below. Should be fairly specific. Mind if I ask if the code is of your doing, or if you're tweaking a ready-made piece of work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can, or so it seems. To begin with, you shouldn't change the ID itself. You should rather add a new database column for version and only update that. (Well you *could* change the ID directly too, but there'd be a lot more code revising for you, plus it wouldn't be a very smart way to do it.)

**First:** Modify your database. I suppose you'll use something like PHPMyAdmin, in which case: Go to the table `submissions`; go to "structure" tab; and there add a field called `version`. Probably right after the `submissionid` field. You can make it type `CHAR(1)`, assuming you won't have versions over Z.

**Second:** Revise your update routine, as follows:

```
// We're modifying the code after this line:
if ((isset($_POST['update'])) && ($_POST['update'] == 'true')) {

// Here we get the current version:
// (You could also get it from your submit form, but then 
//  you'd have to check that the user hasn't messed with it.)

$curr = $newdata->generalSelect('SELECT `version` FROM `submissions` 
             WHERE `submissionid` = ' . (int)  $_POST['submissionid']);

// If the old version is 'a'; it becomes 'b' etc. here:

$version = $curr['version']++;

// Then add it to your array with updated fields:

$updateSubData = array(
    'version' => $version, 
    // ...
```

That should be all there is to this, based on the code you shared. There may be other parts of your application that conflict with it or need other revisions -- you'd know that better (or you're about to find out). And below are a couple of more things to look into, now that I browsed through your code...

**Also:** Be aware that -- unless it's done in your database class -- the variables in your update queries (both) are not sanitized and you may be vulnerable to SQL injection.

**Also:** In your `function reSendSubmissions()` for some reason you are making a separate query for each ID, instead of using a single query like this:

```
WHERE a.`submissionid` IN ("' . implode(',', $ids) . '")
```

You would make that query *before* the loop, which would return a resource for all the rows, and then use a `while($submission = $result->fetch_assoc()) {` as your loop. (That is, assuming your database class returns a standard `mysqli` result resource.)

**Also:** There are some typos in your variable and method names, my eyeballs hurt some with `submisssion_timestampt` and `$newdata->updateSumission`. If these are not giving you errors, good, but you may want to update them sometime across your codebase to make it easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. i have made the changes you suggest in my submit.php and now i get the following  message when i press submit button in re-submit. Fatal error: Call to a member function generalSelect() on a non-object in submit.php on line 37.  The code on line 37: `if ((isset($_POST['update'])) && ($_POST['update'] == 'true')) {

 $curr = $db->generalSelect('SELECT `version` FROM `submissions` 
             WHERE `submissionid` = ' . (int)  $_POST['submissionid']);
 $version = $curr['version']++;

Comment: Oh, I see that you're instantiating the database as `$db` in the first sample of code, but in the second one it's `$newdata` instead. The error you get simply means that there's no object by that name. Just change it and it should work fine. (Updated the answer.) Don't worry about the name "newdata", it's just a generic database object that actually has nothing to do with "new data" as such. You may want to rename that at some point, using e.g. `$db` across the board would will make your code easier to read. Then you'll always know it's a DB object.